# iOS local notification base on day, time frame and number of times?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

After many researches on Stackoverflow and other websites, the only options I can find are either repeat notification on specific day of the week and specific time using:

```
dateComponents = DateComponents()  
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current  
dateComponents.hour = hour  
dateComponents.minute = minute  
dateComponents.weekday = 1  // Sunday  


let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

// the above will trigger every Sunday at whatever time I set it to be.

Another option to send notification is to set time interval but not much options.

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 30, repeats: true)
```

I cannot find any suggestion or solution to trigger notification (number of times starting at certain time on particular day). For example: I want to trigger 5 local notification every Sunday between 8am to 5pm.

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can calculate all the dates and schedule as many individual notifications as you need. Just keep in mind that there's a limit for how many notifications you can schedule, I think it's like 64 or 128, so you'll need to update the scheduled notifications when the user opens the app.

Comment: Does that mean I need to create each notification with an unique Identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to schedule multiple notifications, you need to create multiple notification triggers and register them.

something like:

```
// Simple extension if you have to create multiple of the same object
extension DateComponents {
   static func triggerFor(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> DateComponents {
      var component = DateComponents()
      component.calendar = Calendar.current
      component.hour = hour
      component.minute = minute
      component.weekday = 1
      return component
   }
}

// Add each trigger into an array with the correct date component
let triggers = [
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents.triggerFor(hour: 1, minute: 0), repeats: true),
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents.triggerFor(hour: 2, minute: 0), repeats: true),
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents.triggerFor(hour: 3, minute: 0), repeats: true),
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents.triggerFor(hour: 4, minute: 0), repeats: true),
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents.triggerFor(hour: 5, minute: 0), repeats: true)
]

// Iterate through the array and register the notification with the system
for trigger in triggers {
    // Create the content of the notification
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "My Notification Title"
    content.body = "Body of Notification"

    // Create the request
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, 
                content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the request with the system.
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
       if error != nil {
          // Handle any errors.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: gmogames, thanks for the suggestion. How can I change the component.weekday to be non static? Do/can I add that to the triggerFor(hour: Int, minute: Int, weekday: Int)?

Comment: Yes, just add the parameter you want in the function declaration and use it inside, exactly like you said: `triggerFor(hour: Int, minute: Int, weekday: Int)`

Comment: Hi gmogames, I tried it and seems to do the trick. Thank you for your help. I made a small edit on your original code. Datecomponents with an 's' and use var instead of let on component. Thank you.

Comment: Ah yeah, wrote that from memory :) I approved the edit suggestion and it's updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own times or dates; programming isn't smart and just going to do as you please. Coding is an exact science and needs to be treated as such.

```
var days = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var hours = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
var minute = 0
for day in days {
    for hour in hours {
        dateComponents = DateComponents()

        dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

        dateComponents.hour = hour

        dateComponents.minute = minute

        dateComponents.weekday = 2

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

This should create a series of triggers that will deliver at the top of the hour for hours of `10` `11` `12` `13` `14` on the days of `2` `3` `4` `5` `6`. In human terms, assuming I have these numbers correlated correctly, it should trigger to your users every hour from 10-2 at the top of the hour on M-F.

Tbh - never used `UNCalenderNotificationTrigger`, but assuming it works as you state, this will create triggers for each of those times.